# Error creating IAM Role - Value of property PolicyDocument must be an object

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis

I am creating an IAM role in order to send logs from a stack to kinesis stream in another stack.
When I add permission policy, it fails with the error :

> "Value of property PolicyDocument must be an object".

This is my cloudformation.template.yml :

```
  KinesisRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: {'Fn::Sub': 'Kinesis-Role-${AWS::Region}'}
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [logs.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: KinesisPolicy
        PolicyDocument:
        - Version: '2017-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Action: ['kinesis:PutRecord']
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: '*'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `PolicyDocument` is a list of objects due to `-` in front of `Version`. Also your `Version` is wrong. So it should be:

```
 KinesisRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: {'Fn::Sub': 'Kinesis-Role-${AWS::Region}'}
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [logs.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: KinesisPolicy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Action: ['kinesis:PutRecord']
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: '*'
```

Comment: I just corrected the object error that caused by -, but it was failing with a syntax error. I was looking at all the values except for version. Thankyou so much for pointing that out !